# anchor wrapped li for Slide-out menu in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, slidetoggle

i'm trying to do something like this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/3fo47n21 in wordpress, but i'm having trouble to get the navigation to wrap menu li with anchor tags like this:

```
<nav class="menu-opener">
    <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-inner">
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <li>Accueil</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <li>Portfolio</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <li>Themes</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <li>Templates</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

All i got is this in the header:

```
 <nav class="menu-opener">
     <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
 </nav>
 <nav id="nav-main" class="menu clearfix" role="navigation">

      <?php

      if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :

      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'menu-inner', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><a class="menu-link">%3$s</a></ul>')); 

      endif;

      ?>

 </nav>
```

You guys are my last resort, any advice?

Comment: Its not the answer to your question, but that link is bad html – `ul` elements should only contain `li`'s. Wordpress is doing it right with the `li`'s wrapping the anchors. If you need the anchors to be chunky, make them `display:block;` and `width:100%;` and begin your styling from there.

Comment: Thanx Djave but what i 'm looking for is for the slide-out to work on wordpess just like the example i provided. The li tags are wrapped around with by anchors. Is there another way that i can accomplish that without wrapping li tags with anchors?

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
<nav class="menu-opener">
    <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-inner">
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Accueil</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Themes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Templates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you are going to use `<a>` elements in a `<ul>` element, you need to wrap in in an `<li>` element. You should actually wrap anything in a `<ul>` element with an `<li>` element.

Comment: Im aware of that but in the example the programmer did it like in the link i provided. But let's say i would want to add that class to my wordpress menu anchors, how would you proceed?

Comment: You would add that CSS to wordpress in a custom stylesheet... @Mickeymai